# facebox not working after $.post

Tags: jquery, facebox, .post

i'm using facebox to open a remote page,
i included`jQuery`, `facebox.js` and `facebox.css`
and put it in document.ready like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
    loadingImage: 'imgs/loading.gif',
    closeImage: 'imgs/closelabel.png'
   });
});
```

everything works till i call this function

```
function lecFunc(year)
{
        var name = year + '_lec';
        $.post('php/scripts/lecClickScript.php', { matYear: year, matType: name      }, function (data) {
            document.getElementById("lecs_tbody").innerHTML = data;
            document.getElementById("lecs_boxbody").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("qus_boxbody").style.display = 'none';

        });

    }
```

the facebox doesn't work any more

EDIT :: Solved
Actully the problem was that i was using two jQuery versions
then i read this qustion [Can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

then added this code by the exact sequence

```
    <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/facebox.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/onClick.js" ></script>
    <script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>

    <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log($().jquery); // This prints v2.1.3
            console.log($j().jquery); // This prints v1.4.2
        });
   </script>
```

and in `onClick.js` file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
        loadingImage: 'imgs/loading.gif',
        closeImage: 'imgs/closelabel.png'
    });
});



function lecFunc(year) {
    var name = year + '_lec';
    $.post('php/scripts/lecClickScript.php', { matYear: year, matType: name }, function (data) {
        document.getElementById("lecs_tbody").innerHTML = data;
        document.getElementById("lecs_boxbody").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("qus_boxbody").style.display = 'none';

        $j('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
            loadingImage: 'imgs/loading.gif',
            closeImage: 'imgs/closelabel.png'
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initializing facebox when the page is loaded. In this case, the facebox plugin will be applied only to those elements that are already available in the DOM. After you insert the content with AJAX, the new content won't be initializied with facebox. In order to make it work, you'll have to initialize it after the `$.post`, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function facebox_init() {
        $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
            loadingImage: 'imgs/loading.gif',
            closeImage: 'imgs/closelabel.png'
        });
    }
});

function lecFunc(year) {
    var name = year + '_lec';
    $.post('php/scripts/lecClickScript.php', { matYear: year, matType: name }, function (data) {
        document.getElementById("lecs_tbody").innerHTML = data;
        document.getElementById("lecs_boxbody").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("qus_boxbody").style.display = 'none';

        facebox_init();
    });
}
```

Comment: thanx for your reply,, but when i did it like you said the document.ready didn't initiate the facebox and getting this error in chrome console "Uncaught ReferenceError: facebox_init is not defined"

Comment: i guess the problem was that i was using two versions of jquery :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which element you are expecting `this` within the `$.post` handler function to be, but it won't work like that as it will refer to a different scope. You need to look for the `a` elements within the HTML you appended to the page. Try this:

```
function lecFunc(year) {
    var name = year + '_lec';
    $.post('php/scripts/lecClickScript.php', { matYear: year, matType: name }, function (data) {
        $("#lecs_tbody").html(data).find("a[rel*=facebox]").facebox();
        $("#lecs_boxbody").show()
        $("#qus_boxbody").hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: got this error in chrome console "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" ---- on this function   "$("#lecs_tbody").html(data).find("a[rel*=facebox]").facebox();"